# Could not open kernel policy /etc/selinux/targeted/active/policy.kern for reading

Tags: linux, centos, selinux, erpnext, frappe

by using “Easy Install” to install Frappe ERPNext with this command:

```
sudo python install.py --production --user frappe
```

I am getting this error:

```
TASK [frappe_selinux : Check enabled SELinux modules] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {“changed”: true, “cmd”: “semanage module -l”, “delta”: “0:00:02.254885”, “end”: “2019-03-08 10:07:33.398287”, “msg”: “non-zero return code”, “rc”: 1, “start”: “2019-03-08 10:07:31.143402”, “stderr”: “libsemanage.semanage_read_policydb: Could not open kernel policy /etc/selinux/targeted/active/policy.kern for reading. (No such file or directory).\nOSError: No such file or directory”, “stderr_lines”: [“libsemanage.semanage_read_policydb: Could not open kernel policy /etc/selinux/targeted/active/policy.kern for reading. (No such file or directory).”, “OSError: No such file or directory”], “stdout”: “”, “stdout_lines”: []}
to retry, use: --limit @/tmp/.bench/playbooks/site.retry
```

I am using root account.

I have searched for policy.kern file and it does not even exist in the whole disk.

Any help, please?

Comment: Sounds to me that you need to install some dependencies prior to try to install Frappe. Doing some research, I found https://github.com/frappe/bench. In theory it should install the dependencies: Python 2.7 [Python3.5+ also supported, but not recommended for production], MariaDB 10+, Nginx (for production), Nodejs, yarn, Redis, cron (crontab is required), and wkhtmltopdf (version 0.12.5) (for pdf generation)

Comment: This looks like [ansible output](https://github.com/pdvyas/deploy-erpnext/blob/master/ansible/roles/frappe_selinux/tasks/main.yml). What if you run the command `sudo semanage module -l` from your console? Does it return the same error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file `/etc/selinux/targeted/active/policy.kern` is provided by the package [selinux-policy-targeted](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7.noarch.rpm.html). Try installing it.

```
yum install selinux-policy-targeted
```